# Too many files while trying to read in xarray using dask

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

I'm trying to learn dask to be able to do some calculations on a 18 year NetCDF dataset which has 1464 files for each year and each file being 1MB in size. I can do it in a loop instead but I want to test dask's built-in functions with xarray and see if if its faster and more memory efficient than the conventional climate data operators. So, I'm only testing it by loading the files of just one year and its giving me "too many files error"

```
big_ds = xr.open_mfdataset('path_to_folder/*')
```

I have already modified the open files limit.

```
 ulimit -a
 >>core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
   data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
   scheduling priority             (-e) 0
   file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
   pending signals                 (-i) 62527
   max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
   max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
   open files                      (-n) 8000
   pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
   POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
   real-time priority              (-r) 0
   stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
   cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
   max user processes              (-u) 62527
   virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
   file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: Try `xr.open_mfdataset('path_to_folder/*', autoclose=True)`?

Comment: Thanks, it works with that. I was just afraid if it will automatically close some files from my data folder but it doesn't

Comment: That should be posted as the answer, so that other people will more easily find it.

Comment: Just an FYI, autoclose isn't being used by xarray anymore in the latest version. Just tried this solution and instead I get an error suggesting `If necessary, you can control the maximum number of simultaneous open files with xarray.set_options(file_cache_maxsize=...)`.

Comment: @AWilliams3142 and did it work with that setting? It's interesting because as you can see above, I already set that max number of open files to 8000 using a shell command and still `xr.open_mfdataset()` wasn't working for me.

Comment: For me it doesn't give a `too many files` error. However it does get *very slow* for more than ~1000 files...